# R - Getting Unit Vector

Tags: r

This is likely a duplicate question, but maybe I'm just not using the proper keywords to find what I'm looking for.

Currently, if I have a vector `x`, if I want a unit equivalent I would just do

```
x_unit <- x/sum(x)
```

This is an extremely basic task and may not be made any more efficiently than this, but I'm wondering if there is a function which obtains this task but has an `na.rm` feature or a handles the case when `sum(x) == 0`.

James

Comment: for your second question, there's `x/sum(x,na.rm=TRUE)` ... what do you think the correct answer should be when `sum(x)==0` ???

Comment: I'm already adding max statements and etc to the denominator, it just gets tedious and repetitive.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little function that does what you ask:

```
unit_vec <- function(vec){
   return(vec/(sqrt(sum(vec**2,na.rm=TRUE))))
}
```

let's test it!

```
!> vec
  [1]  87.45438  83.96820 111.47986 106.00922 110.13914 107.26847  86.53061
  [8] 103.61227  85.79385  88.16059        NA
!> unit_vec(vec)
  [1] 0.2832068 0.2719174 0.3610094 0.3432936 0.3566677 0.3473715 0.2802153
  [8] 0.3355315 0.2778294 0.2854937        NA
!> sqrt(sum(unit_vec(vec)**2,na.rm=TRUE))
 [1] 1
```

It works when the sum is 0 too!

```
 > vec2
 [1]  10 -10
 > unit_vec(vec2)
 [1]  0.7071068 -0.7071068
!> sqrt(sum(unit_vec(vec2)**2,na.rm=TRUE))
 [1] 1
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: it does work when the sum is zero, but it is a **different** scaling criterion than the OP requested  (it scales by the L2 norm/RMS rather than the sum ...)

Comment: you're right. sorry, i misunderstood. if you're scaling by the sum, i'm not sure dividing by 0 would make sense. we could just add a stop to the function if sum(vector)==0. what do you think?

Comment: Conveniently, I've been working with numbers which are non-negative. Because of this I've been able to do something like the following:
`x/ifelse(sum(x) == 0, 1, sum(x))`